# ECONNREFUSED with Ethers.js and Node.js

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, web3-providers

```
const { ethers } = require("./node_modules/ethers/lib");

require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  process.env.blockPiWss
);

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error("Limite de tempo excedido"));
    }, ms);
  });
}

async function testConnection() {
  while (true) {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const connectionPromise = provider.getBlock("pending");
    const connection = await Promise.race([connectionPromise, timeout(3500)]);
    const endTime = Date.now();

    console.log(`Intervalo: ${endTime - startTime} ms.`);
    console.log("Provedor:", connection);
  }
}

testConnection();
```

Console logs this at the end of execution

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8548
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)

Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous>
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 8548
}
```

Any solution??

Comment: Connection to same provider worked normally with wscat in windows

Answer (score 0):

`::1` is the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address your own computer. Your computer does not have anything running at port 8548.

- If you want to run your own Ethereum node, follow the instructions and configure it to listen to your incoming connections at port 8545
- If you are using a third party node provider please go to their documentation and customer support to ask how to connect to their nodes